# What to do against the sniping guards in protected shelters?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

In Assassin's Creed Revelations when attacking a Templar Tower and I'm fighting a large group of guards, I often get heavily wounded from gunfire. This seems to come from guards hiding in an extension of the buildings or in a guard house.

Even climbing past them to get any closer is risky, because they can shoot you down and you can't get inside to kill them.

**So what should I do to return them the favor?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if you're standing right next to their hideout, I've found that you can't get them with your sword - you have to get them with a ranged weapon. (Apparently Ezio doesn't have the dexterity to stab guards through an open window, or something.) I've had success taking them out with my hidden pistol and with throwing knives. Bombs, while throwable, never seem to work for me, except maybe for obscuring their vision while I line up my shot.

Comment: Yeah, throw a smoke bomb down, then whip out your gun or crossbow and line them up.  Fortunately, you never have to kill them all.

Comment: Or just lure the guards away from those shelters... when you are out of their sight, they can't shoot you.

Comment: @Fredy, how do you get them to leave their little hideouts? I haven't seen them do that yet.

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller, Not the guard in the shelter, the other guards that are on foot.

And they never annoyed me to climb the tower, so there's no real need to kill them.

Comment: I like to use poison bombs on them.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way I found to take him out is to call assassin's as soon as you have him in your sights and targeted before he takes off. To get close enough I scared him into hiding then targeted all the roof top guards and bunkers (gun men in their blinds) since they're the ones that alert him a majority of the time. Do this followed by returning to a vantage spot out of their perception. Using your assassin's to kill your target also gets you faction challenges, same for when you're clearing out Templars on the roof tops.